# Android - Deserialize this JSON to a POJO

Tags: java, android, json, gson

This is my JSON:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "user_id": "1",
      "item_id": "18630",
      "name": "Unnamed Item",
      "price": "0",
      "description": "",
      "created_at": "2014-01-16 15:31:36",
      "thumbnail": {
        "image50": "http://www.example.com/adsa.jpg",
        "image100": "hhttp://www.example.com/adsa.jpg"
      },...
```

Am I doing the deserialization right?

```
public class ItemListModel {

    private String user_id;
    private String item_id;
    private String name;
    private String price;
    private String category;
    private ArrayList<ThumbnailResponse> thumbnail;

    public ItemListModel(){}

    // getters
}

public class ThumbnailResponse {
    private String image50;
    private String image100;

    public ThumbnailResponse(){     
    }

    //getters
 }
```

I'm just confused, when do we use ArrayList, Array or List for array or object in the JSON file?

One more thing, do I need to make `results` as an array too if that's the case?

Comment: Take a look at `gson` library

Comment: Forgot to mention this. Yeah, I'm trying to use GSON here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have given

```
"thumbnail": {
        "image50": "http://www.example.com/adsa.jpg",
        "image100": "hhttp://www.example.com/adsa.jpg"
      }
```

is not a JsonArray. So you have no need to use `ThumbnailResponse` as an `ArrayList` into `ItemListModel`.

Your Model should be

```
public class ItemListModel {

    private String user_id;
    private String item_id;
    private String name;
    private String price;
    private String category;
    private ThumbnailResponse thumbnail; // Not array List

    public ItemListModel(){}

    // getters
}
```

And

> One more thing, do I need to make results as an array too if that's
>   the case?

Your main data container should be contain ArrayList of `ItemListModel`. Like below

```
ArrayList<ItemListModel> results = new ArrayList<ItemListModel>();
```

Comment: How about `results` up there? Does that also need to be included in an entity? edit: you've answered it

Answer (score 1):

- [] in json -> array
- {} in json -> object or map

in your case

```
// change
private ArrayList<ThumbnailResponse> thumbnail;
// to
private Map<String,String> thumbnail;
```

if you want it the way you declared your java object you need to provide a transformer (depends on the framework you are using)

Comment: Some suggests to use `ThumbnailResponse` class to deserialize `thumbnail` key in JSON. But then, how do I access ThumbnailResponse if using Map?

Comment: if you always have image50, image100 the other suggestion is better. In this solution you access the url like this: itemListModel.thumbnail.get( 'image50' ). It will return the string 'http://www.example.com/adsa.jpg'

Answer (score 1):

```
 List<ItemListModel > ItemListModel ;

         try {

        Type listType = new TypeToken<List<ItemListModel >>(){}.getType();

        result= (List<ItemListModel >) gson.fromJson(result, listType);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Parsing exeption", e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);

    }
this should work
```